# Add choice field options on item addition in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, dropdown

i want to create a functionality or workflow so that when an item is added in a list('Status'), it will automatically get added as an option for a choice drop-down field('status') in another list. How i can achieve that?

Comment: You can use lookup field from first list to another list and use the "Status" column (If it is not choice column in first list)

Comment: @GaneshSanap   Actually we are using XSLT dataform webpart in our page which starts giving error when we are changing the type of field to lookup field. So thats why we want to keep as choice field and update the choices from a separate 'status' list

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with workflows.

Just create a list-workflow on List1 which creates a new Item on List2 with the given item values and set the workflow to "Start workflow automatically when an item is created".

for more detailed information, refer to the following article:

https://www.sharepointsky.com/sharepoint-designer-workflow-create-list-item/

Answer (score 0):

Since you **must** keep it as Choice, you could create a flow that calls a Sharepoint REST API to update the choice field. There is a question on Stack overflow that seems to explain how to update choice using SharePoint Rest API:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027004/update-multiple-choice-field-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api

I did not try it myself, so please bear that in mind..

If you feel that Rest API is a good fit, you could create your own for the purpose. You can take guidance at:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/call-rest-api-from-microsoft-flow/